# LWJGL Shader problems

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am having some trouble with the shaders of my application, the 3d model is a teapot, now this is the result:

[image]

Here is another screenshot from my application before reinstalling my os:

[image]

The problem was before too on other computers, after I reinstalled my os I have this too.

Here are my current shader code I simplified it by removing shading (normals, light position):
**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 330

in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 VP;
uniform mat4 M;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = VP * M * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 330

out vec4 FragColor;


void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

My app can't find the attribute and the uniforms.
What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE:**

**I forgot to compile the shaders, sorry for this.**

Comment: Did the shaders compile and link without errors?

Comment: how can I check that ?

Comment: While attributes and uniforms location return -1 I assume it din't

Comment: Check glShaderiv with GL_COMPILE_STATUS. See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_02#A_reusable_function_to_create_shaders) (it's in C++, but works the same way in Java)

Comment: glShaderi return 2, should it not be 0(false) or 1(true) ?

Comment: Ok my bad, I forgot to compile shader...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to compile shaders, that' s why I got those errors.